# how to set limit for words in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Here i am using bootstrap panels for placing data. here i have some text in bootstrap panel heading. i want to set limit for the text inside the panel heading.

for ex. there is text `Beautiful dam of world located in arizona`.
I want to set limit for `31` words

so that i becomes

`Beautiful dams of world located...`

right now it has

```
<div class="panel-heading">One Seater Motorized Recliner Sofa in Pure Leather White Colour</div>
```

how can i make this?

Comment: You mean 31 characters? I don't think that's possible in pure CSS, as characters differ in width.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you happy with a solution in etiher CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes yes i did i gave min height and width and used javascript to do that now its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick snippet for you to limit the number of characters in a span / div etc by a particular value. This function also includes a slightly neater … at the cutoff point:

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(function(){
  $(".your-div").each(function(i){
    len=$(this).text().length;
    if(len>80)
    {
      $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,80)+'...');
    }
  });
});
// ]]></script>
```

Actually this can also be done very neatly with the ‘ellipsis’ CSS function, but note that this is relatively new and only works on single lines:-

**CSS:**

```
.your-div {
white-space: nowrap;
width: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Its the ‘text-overflow: ellipsis;’ that does all the work, but you do need the other lines for it to work effectively.

Reference : [Limit Number Of Characters](http://slickmedia.co.uk/blog/glenns-blog/limit-number-of-characters-in-div-jquery-css/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a number of char in css. 
But you can define a width and add the property :

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use text-overflow: ellipsis; only works for 1 line text.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use js you can do this in css

```
.panel-heading{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```